# How can I copy all elements of a Matlab string field in an array of structs to another array of structs?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, struct

I have an array of structs that is similar to something of the form:

```
a(1).name ='Art'
a(2).name = 'Bob'
a(3).name = 'Carol'
a(4).name = 'Doris'
```

...

and I would like to copy it. My closest attempt has been to try

```
b = [a.name]
```

which resulted in

```
b = 'ArtBobCarolDoris'
```

I was hoping for

```
b(1) = 'Art'
b(2) = 'Bob'
```

etc

Ultimately, I want to copy `a.name` to another array of structs, e.g. `c`. so that

```
c.FirstName = a.Name
```

i.e.

```
c(1).FirstName = 'Art'
c(2).FurstName = 'Bob'
```

etc

Is there a way to do this other than element by element copying?

Comment: You can't make a struct array without fields as your b(1) = 'Art' example suggests.  A cell array may be what you are after.  Try b = {a.name}

Comment: @excaza - Thanks for your solution. I couldn't accept it, but I did upvote it.

Comment: @user1245262 glad we could help :)

Comment: @excaza - you'll get a 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.' error if you execute b(1) = 'Art'; b(2) = 'Bob';